prevent Integer to Enum Conversion in Spring Boot endpoint
my Enum Values are: RED, BLUE, BROWN
Hi everyone, i have an Enum Field in my class called color.
user posts a request and sets the color parameter on the JSON to "color":"0" , it will automatically convert 0 to RED. How can i throw an exception when that happens to make sure integers are not allowed?
(Implementing Annotation: isValid() doesn't prevent the value from being converted)
How can i block auto conversion from Int to Enum?
I tried to implement an Annotation, but that didnt work.

Try put @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING on your enum.

Assuming you are using jackson, there is a configuration property to override this default behavior.
DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS
package org.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

enum Color {
    RED,
    BLUE,
    GREEN
}

class Item {
    private String name;
    private Color color;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String name, Color color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name :" + name + " color: " + color;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "{\"name\":\"ant\",\"color\":0}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS, true);

        try {
            Item item = objectMapper.readValue(input, Item.class);
            System.out.println(item);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

You can also override this using application properties, or defining a bean.
Read here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper
